# Plot single sensor value in Grafana from InfuxDB

Tags: plot, grafana, influxdb

```
I have stored the data in the InfluxDB database as follows:
```

[image]

where the value is the temperature data.

I want to plot the temperature data in Grafana by reading from the InfluxDB database. I tried the following query, but I could not see the data points on the panel.

SELECT "value" FROM "351561110374515" WHERE ("module_temperature" = 'C') AND $timeFilter
Panel Used: Time Series Panel

Both table and panel view shown as below. From the table view, it is clear that grafana is able to pick up the data points but cannot plot:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Data in value field has to be integer instead of string to plot.